# Clonezilla (Bionic Beaver) not seeing Intel RST RAID0 (even as individual disks)

Tags: raid, mdadm, clonezilla

I'll admit I'm kind of an idiot when it comes to Linux, and I've spent the last three days trying to migrate from a single disk to two disks in RAID 0 using my BIOS' Intel RST RAID solution.

I've been able to perfectly backup my initial disk with Clonezilla, and now that I am in RAID0 I have absolutely no idea how I'm supposed to get Clonezilla to detect my drives.

From what I've read, I should be able to manually assemble the raid using mdadm/dmraid in Clonzilla's commandline, and have messed around with mdadm earlier, getting a solution up on my backup server with two SSDs in another RAID0 config (don't worry, these are a cache that I use to later dump to a spinning disk for longer term storage).

The crux of the problem seems to be that **Clonezilla sees neither the RAID nor the individual disks.** Running `lsblk` doesn't show me the individual disks, and checking for `mdx` devices also comes up empty. It's as if they aren't attached to the system, yet the BIOS recognizes it and if I boot into a Windows installer it sees the RAID fine. The drive was detected on its own when not configured as an RST RAID.

I've been bashing my head against the wall here and nobody I've asked (including searching here and google) seems to understand the issue, so I come here as a last resort.

Are there some drivers I need to load to even get my drives to detect? For reference, I'm using a Hades Canyon NUC and a pair of EX920 drives.

*(Please don't rant at me about how awful RAID0 is or how awful "FakeRAID" is - I'm aware of the pitfalls and have a backup solution.)*

Comment: Try [alternative testing Ubuntu-based images](https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php).

Comment: Have already tried every distribution on that page, including the unstable releases.